# Roll two balanced dice until the sum of the faces equals 7 appears for the first time. Determine the expected value of tosses in this experiment.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Roll two balanced dice until the sum of the faces equals 7 appears for the first time. After that, roll the same two dice until some face 3 appears for the first time. Determine the expected value of tosses in this experiment.

All the possibilities are bellow:
(1,1)(2,1)(3,1)(4,1)(5,1)(6,1)
(1,2)(2,2)(3,2)(4,2)(5,2)(6,2)
(1,3)(2,3)(3,3)(4,3)(5,3)(6,3)
(1,4)(2,4)(3,4)(4,4)(5,4)(6,4)
(1,5)(2,5)(3,5)(4,5)(5,5)(6,5)
(1,6)(2,6)(3,6)(4,6)(5,6)(6,6)\

So, there are 6 possibilities for the sum to be 7. So the probability is $6\over36$ $=$ $1 \over 6$.\

And the probability of face three is going to be $11 \over 36$.

But how do I determine the number of expected tosses?

Comment: Are you familiar with the geometric distribution?

Comment: For what it's worth, a more interesting question would have been the expected value of the sum of the dice on each turn, for all of the required turns.  Here, during *stage 1*, you could capitalize on the fact that $(7)$ is *neutral* with respect to the sum of the dice, so you would expect that the sum of the first $(6)$ rolls (for example) would be $(6 \times 7)$.  *Stage 2* is another matter, because $(3)$ is below the mean die value of $(3.5)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us represent

- $X$: number of tosses until dice sum is 7, $X\sim$ Geometric$(p=1/6)$, $E(X)=1/p=6$.
- $Y$: number of tosses until some face is 3, $Y\sim$ Geometric$(q=11/36)$, $E(Y)=1/q=36/11$.
- $X+Y$: total number of tosses

It is true that $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)=6+36/11=102/11.$

Therefore the expected number of tosses is $E(X+Y)=102/11$.

Comment: Thank you for making me understand, now I see. Upvote!

Comment: You are welcome!